# MySQL query not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, select, insert, phpmyadmin, left-join

I do not understand why my query is not working:

```
INSERT INTO `jos_acymailing_subscriber`(`sleep_breathe`)
  VALUE (`1`)

SELECT `subid` 
  FROM `jos_acymailing_listsub` 
  WHERE `listid` = `8`
   LEFT JOIN `jos_acymailing_subscriber`
  ON `jos_acymailing_listsub`.`subid` = `jos_acymailing_subscriber`.`sleep_breathe`
```

thx

I have a table of users that are subscribed to a mailing lists (the id of the list I am interested in is 8) . The subscription table is a simple intermediary table in a "many to many" relation

In the user table I want to add in a field an integer with 1 for the users that are subscribed to the list 8

So I need to first select the users that are in the intermediary table where the listid is 8 then add 1 in the field sleep_breathe that is in the user table.

The user table structure: name: jos_acymailing_subscriber

Field   Type    Null    Default Comments
subid   int(10) No
email   varchar(200)    No
userid  int(10) Yes     NULL
name    varchar(250)    No
created int(10) Yes     NULL
confirmed   tinyint(4)  No  0
enabled tinyint(4)  No  1
accept  tinyint(4)  No  1
ip  varchar(100)    Yes     NULL
html    tinyint(4)  No  1
key varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
ersmembershipnumber varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
first   varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
title   varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
erj varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
err varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
monograph   varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
breathe varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
membershipcategory  varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
mship_status    varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
copd    varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
sleep_breathe   varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
pro varchar(250)    Yes     NULL

The intermediary table structure is: name: jos_acymailing_listsub

Field   Type    Null    Default Comments
listid  smallint(11)    No
subid   int(11) No
subdate int(11) Yes     NULL
unsubdate   int(11) Yes     NULL
status  tinyint(4)  No

Comment: What exactly is not working? What error message do you get?

Comment: There are two query... execute one by one

Comment: I think he's showing the insert and then his select query after he inserts

Comment: Here is the error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `subid` FROM `jos_acymailing_listsub` WHERE `listid` = `8` LEFT JOIN' at line 3

Comment: no I wanted to do everything in one query I need to have insert something into a table according to a value from another one. I was trying to do it from phpmyadmin. Shall I do it in php?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you have put `VALUE` instead of `VALUES`.

It remains `VALUES` even if there is only one value to insert.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, that is two queries. Also, VALUES not VALUE. Thirdly, I'm not sure MySQL allows a WHERE before the JOIN. Your queries may have to be

```
INSERT INTO `jos_acymailing_subscriber`(`sleep_breathe`) VALUES (`1`);

SELECT `subid` 
FROM `jos_acymailing_listsub` 
LEFT JOIN `jos_acymailing_subscriber`
ON `jos_acymailing_listsub`.`subid` = `jos_acymailing_subscriber`.`sleep_breathe`
WHERE `listid` = `8;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in that statement.

- If you want to insert values retrieved from a SELECT statement, the `VALUES` clause is not needed (in fact it's an error).
- Numbers may not be put into quotes or even backticks.
- The order of the FROM and LEFT JOIN keywords mixed up.

The query to insert values retrieved from a SELECT would be:

```
INSERT INTO jos_acymailing_subscriber (sleep_breathe)
SELECT 1
FROM jos_acymailing_listsub
  LEFT JOIN jos_acymailing_subscriber
     ON jos_acymailing_listsub.subid = jos_acymailing_subscriber.sleep_breathe
WHERE listid = 8
```

One tip: forget the dreaded backticks alltogether so you won't get confused where and for what you need them.

Comment: ok so I am thinking quite wrong. I'd like to insert 1 in the field sleep_breathe but for the subscriber that are subscribed to the listid 8. I wanted to do a Insert like a select with a left join...

Comment: I am not sure I understand.. Where do you put the value to insert?

Comment: @Wiglaf: that's the `1` in the `SELECT 1` part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SELECT will do the VALUES ? ok I ll try.

Comment: @Wiglaf: yes, when you want to insert data based on a SELECT, the VALUES part is not needed. Check the manual for the complete syntax

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2 this is the error message i get.

Comment: @Wiglaf: then apparently there is already a row with the same primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but we do not write on primary keys? that is just a normal field in the db do you want the two tables? how can I send them to you?

Comment: @Wiglaf: post the full definition of the tables involved into your initial question (properly formatted) and explain exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: @Wiglaf: so you don't want to insert rows, you want to update existing rows. That is a completely different question

Answer (score 0):

(1) It should be `VALUES` not `VALUE` in the insert.
(2) The `left join` is part of the `from` clause.  Move the `where` clause to the end.